# Cisco APIC Management Access Policy via CLI?

Tags: cisco

In APIC, the status (enabled/disabled) of HTTP, HTTPS, SSH, and Telnet state can be viewed in the following path:

```
APIC > Fabric > Fabric Policies > Pod Policies > Policies > Management Access
```

What is the equivalent command for this? I need to get this info via SSH.

```
APIC# show f?
 fabric-recovery  Show fabric recovery information
 faults           Show fault information
 fips             Show FIPS information
 firmware         Show firmware information
 flow             Show Netflow information
APIC#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query MO to get all that options.

- Enter APIC CLI and run `bash`
- Execute `icurl -g -X GET 'http://localhost:7777/api/node/mo/uni/fabric/comm-default.json?query-target=children&query-target=subtree'`

Output can be then prettified with [this resource](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) or you can write simple Python script for it:

```
import json

def main():
    data = input("Enter raw json:\n")
    try:
        data = json.loads(data)
    except:
        print("Error in JSON format!")
        return

    print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
    input("\nPress any key...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```